# How can I remap broken arrow key via hidutil?

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, arrow-keys, remap

I have the arrow keys of the keyboard broken so I though to use the combination `Ctrl + "asdw"` instead. As an example, if we want to change the `down arrow key`, my question is: how can I remap it to `Ctrl + s`. Through [KeyCode](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) I got that `Ctrl + s` is:
[image]

Also, [image]

How can I add it to hidutil code knowing that the `down arrow` code is `0x700000051`?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

At the end, since I want to replace the arrowkeys for `Ctrl + "asdw"`, I decided to employ a specific third-party app which I read in the comments of a post: [BetterTouchTool](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/use-customize-third-party-keyboard-mac/). Since the remap is done easily, at the end I replaced all the arrows with `Fn + "asdw"`, as well as any combination of `Opt/Ctr/Cmd + arrow` with `Opt/Ctr/Cmd + Fn + "asdw"`. It is not the best solution but it works nicely fine!